# Keep components always near to each other

Tags: java, swing, jtable, location, scrollpane

I'm trying to create a `JTable` with the first column fixed and the rest of the columns scrollable. Now I have two `JTable`, the first one that has just one fixed column and the other one, without the first column, located on the right.

And here's the problem, if I need to resize the first fixed column then it creates an empty space between the two `JTable`s. So I would like to set a new location for the second `JTable` (or find a way to keep the tables always near to each other although resizing of the first one)

How can I do that?

Comment: For better help sooner pleae provide a valid [mcve] or [sscce](http://sscce.org/). Without it we're blind and cannot give an accurate answer.

Comment: I assume you mean that you want to scroll the second table horizontally. If that's what your'e doing, why not just using the second JTable header instead of the first table? see http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/TableRowHeaderExample.htm

Comment: Exactly, that's what I'm trying to do. But I don't know if I can do that in a situation like that http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/JTreeTablecomponent.htm  Where the first column is a JTree (with expandable nodes)